# How to get rid of halo effect when focus stacking with helicon focus?

Tags: macro, macro-lenses, focus-stacking

I've a Nikon D810 and am using the nikor 105mm f2.8 macro lens.

I'm also using helicon focus to focus stack images. Unfortunately the resulting picture has a halo effect on some the boundaries of some objects in the image.

What is the best way to completely avoid this?

Comment: You can try to increase the radius of the area the program uses to determine the contrast, [see here](http://www.heliconsoft.com/helicon-focus-main-parameters/).

Comment: Another reason can be movement of the image - sometimes you can get rid of the halo by removal of one (or more) of the images in the stack.

Comment: @CountIblis that was the first thing I tried as per the docs but  it didn't make a difference.

Comment: @ChrisWalton interesting. I should try that next time. Kinda tedious to hunt through pictures (esp. large NEF files)

Comment: It is not quite as bad as it seems to search through the images - it is usually obvious roughly where in the stack the image lies, and only a portion of the stack needs searching.

Answer (score 2):

I just increased the DOF from 3.2 to 8 and all the halo just went away.

Please note I did play around with increasing the radius setting but that didn't make a difference.